# Transformers (Attention is all you need) with Word2Vec or GloVe?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, transformer-model

I am new to NLP and i am confused about the embedding.
Is it possible, if i already have trained GloVe embeddings / or Word2Vec embeddings and send these into Transformer? Or does the Transformer needs raw data and do its own embedding?
(Language: python, keras)

Answer (score 1):

Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BERT_(language_model)

> BERT models are pre-trained from unlabeled data extracted from the
> BooksCorpus with 800M words and English Wikipedia with 2,500M
> words.

Whether to train your model depends on your data.

For simple english text, the out-of-the-box model should work well.

If your data concentrates on certain domain e.g. job requisitions and job applications, then you can extend the model by training it on your corpus (aka transfer learning).

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training

Answer (score 0):

If you train a new transformer, you can do whatever you want with the bottom layer.

Most likely you are asking about pretrained transformers, though.  Pretrained transformers such as Bert will have their own embeddings of the word pieces.  In that case, you will probably get sufficient results just by using the results of the transformer.